# How to change a viewcontroller of a slidemenu?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 separate VC-s that each need to be displayed to the user depending on a state of the app. This is how I create my original slidemenu in AppDelegate, it works as intended:

```
let mainVC = MainNavVC.create()!
let leftMenuVC = LeftMenuVC.create()!
slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: mainVC, leftMenuViewController: leftMenuVC)
self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

But when I try to change the leftMenuVC the screen goes black, the menu button just stops working and tapGesture still shows the wrong menu. Here is a code I call to change the slidemenu:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.slideMenuController?.leftViewController = AnotherLeftMenuVC.create()!
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.slideMenuController
```

I also tried an alternative approach to change the leftMenuVC:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: MainNavVC.sharedInst!,
leftMenuViewController: AnotherLeftMenuVC.create()!)
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = appDelegate.slideMenuController
appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

This will turn my screen black but tapGesture will at least show the correct leftMenu.

How to make this work ?

Comment: Consider using two `UIViews` instead of two `UIViewControllers`? Without any more description of why you chose this design - two completely different menus and using `AppDelegate` to designate which to use dynamically at... well, what point in the **app** lifecycle?... it's rather hard to help out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I chose this design because I outsourced cutting sketch files into the app and the freelancer implemented that leftmenu with a new viewcontroller.
Which menu to use is checked every time the user navigates to a certain screen.

Comment: @MarkoRatas See my answer below.

Comment: Not to sound critical, but, okay two pieces of criticism - meant politely. (1) Why should somebody using Sketch designate where a view controller works? (2) More importantly, under most *normal* circumstances `AppDelegate` is meant for tapping into the OS (or iOS), not dynamically changing something **within** the app's classes. With what you've posted I'm still sticking with my original thought - not good design. (And if you agree, stick with *your* thought and push back on the designers.)

Comment: Yeah, in the end I did what you told me to do in your first comment. Just used another view. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick. I tested it in your library's sample project. This works but it's up to you to clean the code and make the unwrapping optionals and castings safer.

Basically the trick is to embed your `leftController` or `rightController` into a `UINavigationController`. And access such navigationController using the way you're trying to access the `slideMenuController` in the `AppDelegate`. And then replace the `viewControllers` of that navigationController.

In the `viewDidLoad()` of the `MainViewController` (I'm talking about the sample project, you should be familiar with this or relate your mainController here). I have this block of code that will be executed in 5 seconds ;) I use this approach when testing something, just to save time for the sake of demo.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerCellNib(DataTableViewCell.self)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(5)) {
            let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RightViewController") as! RightViewController

            ((appDel.window?.rootViewController as! ExSlideMenuController).leftViewController as! UINavigationController).viewControllers = [rightViewController]
        }
    }
```

and in the appDelegate, I embed the controller into a navigationController:

```
let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: leftViewController), rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
```

This should help you out.

Comment: Which sample project are you talking about?

Comment: Your library's sample project.

Comment: Can you refer to that project with a URL?

Comment: I tried, wasn't able to make it work. Maybe there's a simpler way. If not then I will just alter the way my original slideMenuController looks. Outcome will be the same.

Comment: Meh. It's working on my side. By the looks/structure of the library, changing the side controller isn't complex. Try it again, maybe you're missing some step. Good luck